# jQuery Validate: Enable submit button only after form successfully validates

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using [jQuery Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org) to validate a form. Individual fields validate as desired, but my project demands the form's submit activate only after all validation checks successfully pass. (I'm aware of the UX problems with this, the decision is out of my hands.)

I am struggling to enable the submit button *immediately* even when I know validation is successful. My code doesn't return true until the user triggers another `change` event:

```js
$('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$('form').validate({
    onfocusout: function(element) { $(element).valid(); }, //I need each field to validate as it is typed into, per a client requirement
    rules: {
        name_required: "required",
        name_number: "number",
        name_required_select: "required"
    }
});

//*THIS* is where I'm going wrong
$('input').on('blur keyup', function(){
    if( $('form').validate().checkForm() ){
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', '');  
    }
});
```

I know something's wrong because if I call `$('form').validate().checkForm()` from the console I see the individual validation checks pass (without needing to click in/change any other field), and I get `true`. For some reason I just can't get that when binding to `keyup` and other events on my `input`s.

[Test case to demonstrate problem.](https://codepen.io/edadams/pen/NWGepGb)

1. Type anything in the first field, select something for the third field.
2. The submit button *should* activate (the required validation rules are now met).
3. Clicking inside any field, or entering a value in the optional fields, will activate my submit button.

**Desired behaviour:**

I need the submit button to activate immediately upon passing validation checks, without this extra step of going back and changing something.

**What I've tried:**

1. Binding to `change`, `keyup`, and `blur` for all `input`s in every combination I can think of, doesn't help.
2. A nasty hack using `setInterval` and waiting until `valid()` returns true, which works but I worry about constantly running that (this form is very long and the user will be on the page for 
   a while).
3. I know the library has a `validate()` method but for some reason it triggers a validation check I don't want at that time (`if( $('form').validate() ){ ...`). All I need is a boolean true/false, so that method wasn't suitable for my purposes. I feel I need to use `checkForm()` which doesn't trigger validation when invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional change event for your select box because if it's the last thing you change, the form won't validate until then. You also need to set 'disabled' to `true` or `false`.

```
$('#submit').attr('disabled', true);

...

//*THIS*
function checkValidation() {
    if ( $('form').validate().checkForm() ) {
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);  
    }
}

$('input').on('blur keyup', checkValidation);

$('select').on('change', checkValidation);
```

You might even be able to use the `change` event on your `input` instead of `blur` and keyup`, so that's something for you to try if you wish.

Comment: Kicking myself it was something so simple as forgetting to watch for `select`s as well. Thank you so much.